# `bodegraph` not smooth anymore

Tags: bodegraph, smooth

When I try to plot the Bode using the manual of `bodegraph` package, I notice the phase plot isn't straight (when vertical), see
[image]

So I have used `const plot` option and the vertical part of phase plot is straight, but magnitude plot is not smooth anymore, see
[image]

Is is possible to keep the magnitude plot smooth, while at the same time the phase plot has vertical part?

This is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
    \begin{scope}[yscale=3/40]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{20}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100]{-2:2}
    {\POAmpAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POAmp{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,yscale=3/90]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-90}{0}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100]{-2:2}
    {\POArgAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
    \begin{scope}[yscale=3/40]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{20}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100,const plot]{-2:2}
    {\POAmpAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POAmp{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,yscale=3/90]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-90}{0}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100, const plot]{-2:2}
    {\POArgAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience in Bodegraph. So please don't grill me if this proposal is useless. ;-)

However, I do now that one may use `samples at` in order to get plots consisting just of straight lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
    \begin{scope}[yscale=3/40]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{20}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100]{-2:2}
    {\POAmpAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POAmp{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,yscale=3/90]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-90}{0}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100]{-2:2}
    {\POArgAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/4]
    \begin{scope}[yscale=3/40]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-20}{20}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples at={-2,0,2}]{-2:2}
    {\POAmpAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POAmp{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-2.5cm,yscale=3/90]
    \semilog{-2}{2}{-90}{0}
    \BodeGraph[asymp lines,samples=100, const plot]{-2:2}
    {\POArgAsymp{6}{0.3}}
    \BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{6}{0.3}}
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]